# What does clock/signal speed actually do?

Tags: signal, i2c, spi, clock-speed

This is may be a silly questions but I am curious.
I know that in circuits power lines are at speed near light but why are signal lines so different?
Let's say I use I2C(MCP23017) I can choose between

- 100 kHz
- 400 kHz
- 1.7 MHz

while SPI allows up to 10MHz.

For the Ethernet connection I also need a 50MHz Clock signal.

As I know this board doesn't like to many questions at the same time I try to keep my focus on the most important for me.

What does these numbers mean for my circuit (Is bigger always better)?

Comment: signal lines are also near light speed when measured in units of `m/s`. `kHz` etc is speed; but not in the sense of distance/time but in transitions/time.

Comment: What does transitions in this context mean ? Do I understand it right when I think of a outpin pin from a mc and it can turn high/low as fast as these numbers go?

Comment: yes. number of voltage level changes or changes of some physical parameter of the signal.

Comment: Sometimes slower is better ... lower power requirement, less RF interference, where you don't need fast communications.

Comment: Better for performance, but not for power consumption and noise immunity.

Comment: I think you might be confusing two mostly unrelated measurements of "speed". Think of your internet connection. It has a certain bandwidth and a certain latency (ping). Bandwidth = transitions per second. For your power lines you are thinking about latency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The clock speed (well, data rate) that a wire can carry is limited ultimately by its bandwidth and the presence of noise. This is formalized in Shannon’s Information Theory.

Some light reading here: https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/claude-e-shannon-founder/

Anyway, the data rate chosen depends on the needs of the application.

I2C is designed to be low cost, highly compatible as a shared bus, and somewhat tolerant of poor signal integrity: slow rise times, reflections and system noise, and the fact that it only uses two wires. Even within I2C, there are additional signal integrity considerations that arise with the faster modes.

Notably, I2C doesn’t treat wires as transmission lines, but as lumped RC networks. The rise and fall time are determined by the trace capacitance and pull-up resistor and open-collector drive strength.

Faster buses do treat wires as transmission lines with a characteristic impedance. When you think of signals flying ‘near the speed of light’ you’re thinking of a transmission line. In fact any wire is a transmission line, but to do a good job as one it must be designed with good signal integrity (consistent impedance, proper termination, reasonable inductance and capacitance per unit length) and have the electronics matched to it.

So the RMII bus (Ethernet MAC - PHY connection) 50MHz demands more care in layout, and is also point-to-point. It’s limited by the delay from the main clock launch to the returning data from the far end: turn-around time. RGMII overcomes this with source-synchronous clocks so it can run at 125MHz.

Normal SPI has the same issue: turn-around time limits read cycle time. Nevertheless it is normally rated for up to 108MHz, which is achievable with careful design and fast drivers.

There’s even faster SPI variants that adopt a kind of source-sync clock. These go up to 200MHz. SPI descendant Hyperbus can do 400MHz double-data rate.

So the takeaway is, clock speed depends on the transmission medium as the ultimate limit, followed by limits imposed by what you need, how much design effort you’re willing to invest, and how much you’re willing to spend on hardware to meet your need.

Answer (score 1):

It simply means that with a faster clock you can update the GPIO extender pins faster, using less time, which allows for using the time or the bus for other purposes.

But different buses have different specifications, which dictate what frequencies can be used, or must be used.

The buses you ask are all for different purposes, so they have quite different clock requirements.

The point of I2C is that it uses only two pins in open-drain mode, which limits the speed to rather slow communication, mainly between onboard sensors. The original standard from the 80s has been upgraded many times for faster speeds. The I2C "Standard Mode" requirements allow up to 100 kHz clock, "Fast Mode" requirements allow up to 400 kHz clock, "Fast Mode Plus" requirements allow up to 1 MHz clock, and "High Speed Mode" goes up to 3.4 MHz. The I2C version of the chip you ask about can implement only up to 1.8 MHz.

SPI also mainly meant for communications between onboard chips. It is not standardized in any speed grades, and since it uses standard push-pull outputs, it can go up to any speed the chips can implement, from single MHz values to several tens of MHz. The SPI version of the chip you ask about can implement only up to 10 MHz.

Ethernet is completely different, and does not compare in any way with the chip you are asking about. It is an interface to exchange packets over a local network of devices. And it has standards as well - one of the standards is 100 Mbps. To achieve 100 Mbps with 50 MHz clock you talk about, it must refer to communications between MCU and PHY chip over RMII bus, which uses 2 bits per clock to achieve 100 Mbps. The wider MII bus uses 25 MHz clock and transfers 4 bits per clock to achieve 100 Mbps.